# concat just one element of 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript so this question might be very basic..

I have a list like this:

```
[ ["word",number],["word2",number2]......]
```

I want to get one string like

```
concat_str = "word\nword1\n....."
```

I see that for 1d array there is this join..

```
  array.join()
```

method..

But how do i do this for just one element of 2d array.

Comment: Please don't include "Any suggestions. Thanks" in your question. Our style focuses on the question, not on pleasantries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no simple function for what you want to do because what you want is a bit more specific: you want a specific element of each array to be concatenated.  Not too hard, though:

```
array.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
    return prev += cur[0] + "\n";
}, '').trim();
```

Comment: Mozilla was nice enough to provide compatibility code for All ECMAScript5 changes (or at least for arrays): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce -- I would rather cease supporting IE8 so it can die

Comment: Oh totally; you still got my upvote (not that you need the rep!) Just noting for n00bs who stumble across.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '';
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    str += arr[x].join('') + "\n";
}
```

Comment: HI.. it concates.. the "number" aslo.. I want just the "word" part?